# KVM VM won't start after installation - Loading initial ramdisk

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, lvm

I installed my first KVM VM on a debian 9.3 host, with debian 9.3 client in the VM with virt-install. The host is a new and clean installation on a Dell Laptop. The only thing altered by me was the network setup to bridge the eno1 interface for the VM.

what I did:

/etc/network/interfaces:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet manual
iface eno1 inet6 manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.0.0.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 10.0.0.0
    broadcast 10.0.0.255
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    bridge_ports eno1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
    dns-nameservers 212.186.211.21 195.34.133.21

# autoconfigure ipv6 for
iface eno1 inet6 auto
    accept_ra 1
iface br0 inet6 auto
    accept_ra 1
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 212.186.211.21
nameserver 195.34.133.21
```

and appended following to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
#  disable netfilter on the bridge
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
```

Installed the KVM tools: `apt-get install virtinst`

I created a logical volume for the VM with: `lvcreate -n active-directory -L 20GB ganetti-node-001-vg` and then I installed the VM with like this:

```
virt-install \
    --name active-directory-master \
    --ram 2048 \
    --location http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/stable/main/installer-amd64/ \
    --disk path=/dev/ganetti-node-001-vg/active-directory \
    --cpu host-model-only \
    --vcpus 2 \
    --os-type linux \
    --os-variant debian9 \
    --network bridge=br0 \
    --graphics none \
    --console pty,target_type=serial \
    --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

Installation runs, I set up language, keyboard, root and main user, partitioning and package selection (just xface and ssh server), writing grub to partition and restart. On first startup it hangs here:

[image]

When checkout what's running, I get the following output:

[image]

What I tried so far:

- create a LVM partition into the logical volume during the installation of the VM.
- create a primary partition into the logical volume during the installation of the VM.
- install over a ssh connection
- install directly on the laptop (as the keyboard mapping is broken during editing the grub2 startup script, but was also broken.)
- select following in the grub2 start menu of the VM:

  - the standard installation.
  - repair mode (is it named like this?)

Now I am out of ideas what to try next. Thanks for any support for an KVM noob!

Comment: Isn't it odd that virt-install is still running?  I repeated your exercise, minus the network and console params, and at the end of the installation, when the VM needed rebooting, the installation finished.  Then I had to run "virtsh start" and virt-viewer, and saw the VM booting.  When I connect using "virtsh console", I am connected, but can't do a thing.